# Logging in PHP and WordPress specifically

Tags: php, logging, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress plugin and would like to leave some log messages whenever certain things happen so I can debug issues when they come up in a client's WP install.

What's the best way to create log messages across my plugin? Will PHP's `syslog` suffice?

I know `error_log` is very common for debugging but I'm not sure it's a good idea to log normal messages wit this.

Comment: This is a bit vague, but I would leave the error log for errors and log anything else to a different log.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

> #### WP_DEBUG_LOG
>
> WP_DEBUG_LOG is a companion to WP_DEBUG that causes all errors to also be saved to a debug.log log file inside the /wp-content/ directory. This is useful if you want to review all notices later or need to view notices generated off-screen (e.g. during an AJAX request or wp-cron run).
>
> Note that this allows you to write to /wp-content/debug.log using PHP's built in error_log() function, which can be useful for instance when debugging AJAX events.
>
> `define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`
>
> Note: for WP_DEBUG_LOG to do anything, WP_DEBUG must be enabled (true). Remember you can turn off WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY independently.

Comment: I've seen this but it just doesn't feel right to pepper my production code with `error_log`s.

Comment: There's no cleaner way built into wordpress (unfortunately). There might be other plugins which you can use to allow debugging, or you can write a simple wrapper function around error_log that won't write if DEBUG=false